# Why did my SVN repository move to a different path?

Tags: svn

After our source control machine rebooted, the SVN path to our repository somehow changed:

Before:
svn://machineName/OurProject

After:
svn://machineName/someFolder/OurProject

How do I fix this?

Comment: Michael, I considered posting on Server Fault, but because it's a source control problem, I thought it could be considered more a programming question.

Comment: Source control is a very very gray area. I've seen questions on that in all three sites taken as valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the SVN server, use the `-r` flag to point to the correct root repos folder

`svnserve -d -r /path/to/someFolder`

Comment: Running any command on svnserve issues a dll error message. Woops. Maybe that is related to this issue. I'll reinstall SVN server.

Comment: Reinstalling fixed it, so I'm marking yours as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

It appears someone (intentionally or not) changed the path. To fix your working copy:

```
svn switch --relocate svn://machineName/OurProject svn://machineName/someFolder/OurProject
```

Comment: Thanks, but no thanks. I'd like to keep all our working copies pointing to the path original path.

Comment: Since you had no idea why the path changed I thought you couldn't manipulate the server.